# Silverlight - MVVM friendly way way to pass parameter into embedded user control?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, user-controls

Here's the scenario:

I have an "order lookup" user control that allows a user to browse through orders and select one. The order lookup user control has an "order detail" user control embedded in it which is not visible until an order is selected, at which point it displays the order details.

The question is - how to pass the selected OrderID into the order detail user control and get the order to be loaded (i.e. set the order detail viewmodel's CurrentOrderID property, and call it's LoadOrder method) from the order lookup user control, in an MVVM friendly way (i.e. without code references to either user control's controls).

It would be straightforward if I could reference the active instance of the order detail's viewmodel from the order lookup's viewmodel, but I can't see how to do that.

My current approach is to make the CurrentOrderID property static (so I can set it from the order lookup's viewmodel without any reference to the active instance of the order detail's viewmodel) and have a timer with a 1s interval running in the order detail's viewmodel checking for changes in the CurrentOrderID property. However this has a bad smell to it and some unwanted side effects!

Comment: Are the UserControls part of the same view?  Are you using MVVM-light or something similar?

Comment: Separate views. Its all hand coded - no framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have two views with two ViewModels. Then, depending on the MVVM framework (if any) you use, you should use messaging mechanism for exchanging data between ViewModels (Mediator pattern).

Orders VM sends message that selected Order changed (via Messenger) and OrderDetail VM receives this message and reacts accordingly.

Messenger is responsible on one side for subscribing receivers on the other side for sending to subscibers. So no need to periodically check for anything, it should be event based.

Consider using for example MVVM Light and its `Messenger` class:

http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/